# pass a variable value in crontab

Tags: sql, bash, shell, cron

i am trying to perform a SQL file importation into my mysqlDB, well this should be happening every 5 mints, therefore i used crontab -e:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/mysql -u root -pexpress azuzDB < /home/admin/Desktop/backups/backup_n1.sql
```

well the cron job works fine, but in a matter of issues the backup_n*.sql name changes every 5 mints also, and i am interested in the latest sql file in the folder so i came with idea to get the latest file by applying this command:

```
ls /home/admin/Desktop/backups -Art | tail -n 1
```

so i would like to pass this command output which is = (backup_n*.sql "most recent")

in the importation cron job command i use in crontab any solution to pass variables in a crontab of centos ??

the last output would be something like this:

```
 * * * * * lastSQL= ls /home/admin/Desktop/backups -Art | tail -n 1
 */5 * * * * /usr/bin/mysql -u root -pexpress azuzDB < /home/admin/Desktop/backups/$lastSQL
```

Comment: Might be better to create a script doing all of this. Otherwise, the cronjob will be quite difficult to read. `file=$(ls -Art | tail -n 1)` should do, also.

Comment: i did not get it also the script should be instantly running with the importation command so, how i can make the output of a script the input at the end of the importation command

Comment: does pipe "  |  " does the trick ?

Comment: You can eventually use `/usr/bin/mysql -u root -pexpress azuzDB < /home/admin/Desktop/backups/$(ls -Art /home/admin/Desktop/backups -Art | tail -n 1)`

Comment: you are an angle :) thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in comments, the way to get the last file can be:

```
ls -Art | tail -n 1
```

If you wrap it within `$()`, it will be evaluated whenever you place it. Hence, you can do:

```
/usr/bin/mysql -u root -pexpress azuzDB < /home/admin/Desktop/backups/$(ls -Art /home/admin/Desktop/backups -Art | tail -n 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to create a shell script, say called /home/admin/import.sh

```
$ cat import.sh 
#! /bin/bash
dir=/home/admin/Desktop/backups/
file=$( ls -At  $dir )
/usr/bin/mysql -u root -pexpress azuzDB < ${dir}/${file}
```

and have your crontab to look like:

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/bash /home/admin/import.sh
```

Comment: yes it would be more appropriate and easier to implement